# iOS in-app-purchase (IAP) hosting content with Apple

Tags: ios, upload, hosting, in-app-purchase

I have an app uses IAP and has been thru a few editions. The other day, I accidentally clicked the button for hosting content with apple, and I found I could not undo this. Worse thing is that I could not test the IAP in sandbox environment UNLESS I upload the content. I remember there was a lucky guy posted here saying that he had such situation and Apple removed the option for him after he wrote apple. However, I don't have such luck. I wrote and called apple to request removal of the flag. After 3-week waiting and handful phone calls, I got the answer saying that flagging hosting content option is not reversible. I guess I have to go other way, but I have question and uncertainty, along the steps I can do.

1, I'm planning to upload a 1-line text file with the IAP. 
Is this fine?

2, This is the first I make a .pkg file. I downloaded PackageMaker, and dropped the 1-line file to its window and I made a pkg, also followed installation guide and installed it --- but I could not find where it is installed (I chose Mac HD...). Question is:
Is this alright? A text file becomes a installation package?

3, I guess in normal situation, when users buy IAP with content, the app should handle the downloaded packagecontent.pkg and open and install it, right? In my case, I just ignore the downloading step and content. No code need to be added to my current IAP-handling script, is this okay?

4, I will use Application Loader to load the package for the given IAP. The first time for me too. Any often-made mistakes that I can learn and avoid before I actually do this?

Thank you very much your input!!!!

Answer (score 7):

I'm in the process of adding some content hosted IAPs right now too. I can tell you what I've learned so far:

First, yes you should be able to include any file that you want to include in your IAP package (including a 1-line text file).

I used Xcode to create my IAP package files (containing both text and image files) and uploaded the packages to iTunes Connect. Check out this very helpful tutorial for how to do this: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_and_Creating_App_Store_Hosted_Content_for_iOS_6_In-App_Purchases.

You do need to handle the download of the hosted content yourself after a purchase is made.

Good luck!